# Calculating an integral with absolute value

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, stochastic-calculus, problem-solving

I want to calculate below integration in terms of $a$,$q_1$,$q_2$ and $q_3$ but don't really know how to do.

$ \int_0^{2\pi} |\sin (a-b) \cos (a-b)| \: P \: db$

the form of $P$ is not known but one can use below relations to calculate above integral:

$ \int_0^{2\pi} \sin b \: \sin b \: P \: db = q_1$

$ \int_0^{2\pi} \cos b \: \cos b \: P \: db = q_2$

$ \int_0^{2\pi} \cos b \: \sin b \: P \: db = q_3$

not that the question is asked because I don't know what to do with absolute value. a is a parameter and not a definite value

Is there any really clever guy who could solve this problem?
any answers is highly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.pinkmonkey.com/studyguides/subjects/trig/chap4/t2.gif

Comment: I feel like there needs to be some bounds on the integral, or this doesn't make sense (to me at least)

Comment: @SimpleArt but what to do with absolute value denoted by ||?

Comment: If they are definite integrals, you break it up over when it is positive and negative.  If not, I am unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $$|\sin (a-b) \cos (a-b)|>0,$$

then

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{2\pi} |\sin (a-b) \cos (a-b)| \: P \: db\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} \sin (a-b) \cos (a-b) \: P \: db\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\{(\sin(a)\cos(b)-\sin(b)\cos(a))(\cos(a)\cos(b)+\sin(a)\sin(b)\}Pdb\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\{\sin(a)\cos(a)\cos^2(b)+\cos(b)\sin(b)\sin^2(a)-\sin(b)\cos(b)\cos^2(a)\\&-\cos(a)\sin(a)\sin^2(b)\}Pdb\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\{\sin(a)\cos(a)\cos^2(b)+\cos(b)\sin(b)\sin^2(a)-\sin(b)\cos(b)\cos^2(a)\\&-\cos(a)\sin(a)\sin^2(b)\}Pdb\\
&=\sin(a)\cos(a)\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2(b)Pdb+\sin^2(a)\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(b)\sin(b)Pdb-\cos^2(a)\int\sin(b)\cos(b)Pdb-\cos(a)\sin(a)\int\sin^2(b)Pdb\\
&=\sin(a)\cos(a)q_2+\sin^2(a)q_3-\cos^2(a)q_3-\cos(a)\sin(a)q_1\\
&=\frac{\sin(2a)}{2}\left(q_2-q_1\right)-\cos(2a)q_3
\end{align}

If $$|\sin (a-b) \cos (a-b)|<0,$$

then we have an overall negative sign.

Comment: It is a wrong answer. The sign of term inside the || depends on b which is changing when integrating.

Comment: Yes, clearly. But either the term inside the || is either negative or positive, no? Without more information, it cannot be determined when the sign of this term is positive or negative (i.e. the interval(s) when b>a etc.).

Comment: My answer complete, given the information you have provided.